# Subspace of Lindelöf space is not Lindelöf: Example

Tags: general-topology

The Munkres' topology book provides Example 30.5 (p.193, 2nd Ed) for a subspace of a Lindelöf space that need not be Lindelöf as follows:

> The ordered square $I_0^2$ is compact; therefore it is Lindelöf
>   trivially. However, the subspace $A = I \times (0,1)$ is not Lindelöf.
>   For $A$ is the union of the disjoint sets $U_x = \{x\} \times (0,1)$,
>   each of which is open in $A$. This collection of sets is uncountable,
>   and no proper subcollection covers $A$.

I could largely understand this argument. But it is not clear to me how $U_x$ is open in $A$. Could someone please explain? Thanks.

RD

Comment: If you want a simpler example, let $X$ be any set of uncountable cardinality, and let $Y = X \cup \{x\}$ for some $x\notin X$.  Declare a set to be open iff it's $Y$, empty, or a subset of $X$.  Then $Y$ is compact (the only open set which contains $x$ is $Y$ itself), but the subspace $X$ is not Lindelof.

Comment: Dear DeVito, could you explain more. I cannot understand why Y is compact.

Comment: @whitegreen Any open cover has to contain $Y$ since no other open set contains $x$. But then the refinement that only contains $Y$ is a finite subcover. Hence $Y$ is compact.

Answer (score 4):

The set $U_x$ is open, since the topology on the ordered square is not the standard Euclidean topology.  The definition of the order on the square is lexicographic, ie $(x_1,y_1) < (x_2, y_2)$ if either $x_1 < x_2$ or if $x_1 = x_2$ and $y_1 < y_2$.  The corresponding order topology is generated by sets of the form 
$$
\{ (x, y) : (x_1, y_1) < (x,y) < (x_2, y_2)\}
$$

In this example $U_x$ is obtained by taking $(x_1, y_1) = (x,0)$ and $(x_2, y_2) = (x,1)$.

Comment: Ah, I see that now. Thank you Rolf! - RD

Comment: According to the given notation in the question, Shouldn't the element be defined as $x$ x $y$ instead of $(x,y)$.

Answer (score 2):

A simpler example is, in Munkres' notation, $\overline{S_{\Omega}}$. (The closure of the first uncountable well ordered set in the order topology.)

The space is compact and therefore Lindelöf trivially, (It is compact because it is a well ordered set with a maximum in the order topology, but you can find other ways to prove it's Lindelöf.) but $S_{\Omega}$, the same space without the maximum, is not Lindelöf as the open cover $\{[0,\alpha)\}_{\alpha\in S_{\Omega}}$, has no countable subcover. Note every countable set in $S_{\Omega}$ is bounded.

Answer (score 0):

I support Rolf Hoyer's answer. Since I'm reading the same book with you, a quick answer to

"why $U_x=\{\}\times(0,1)$ is open in $= \times(0,1)$ (as a subspace of ordered square)?"

is $\S 16 $ (see Figure 16.1) of the book where shows a counterexample.
When inventing the case of  $= \times(0,1)$, Munkres intended to disconnect all vertical lines (thus they are uncountable) by deleting the lowest/highest horizontal line.

Given

1. dictionary order $(a\times b, c\times d) $ for $a<c$ and for $b<d$ if $a=c$.
2. the space $I \times (0,1)$

We can see that the set $\{ x \}\times(0,1)$ is the "vertical" interval $(x\times 0, x\times1)$ (a form of dictionary order), so the set  $\{\}\times(0,1)$ is an open subset of $ \times(0,1)$ (as a subspace of ordered square) .